# graphql - how to filter a nested list

Tags: graphql, hotchocolate

I am currently trying to filter a nested list based on a given id, but don't understand the syntax required. Although I have altered the entities and properties, this is what I am attempting

```
{
  companies{
    company{
      id,
      name,
      offices(where:{officeId: {eq: 2}}){
        officeId,
        address,
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the returned data, I would like ALL companies and their offices where the office id is equal to 2. Is this possible and how would I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This way you filter the offices inside all companies
Try this

```
{
  companies(where:{company: {offices: {some: {officeId: {eq: 2}}}}}){
    company {
      id 
      name 
      offices {
        officeId
        address
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thx, the keyword **some** made the magic. Other useful operators **every**, **none**. A few documentation https://keystonejs.com/docs/guides/filters#to-many

Comment: I haven't tried it but this doesn't seem equivalent. It would filter out companies where there was no such office ID in the group, but list all offices of those who DO have office ID #2 in their list. The query as described suggests ALL companies included, and their office lists will be either empty, or contain only ID #2.

Comment: @JoshSutterfield not sure if i follow

`It would filter out companies where there was no such office ID in the group, but list all offices of those who DO have office ID #2 in their list.`

That was the question of OP

`The query as described suggests ALL companies included, and their office lists will be either empty, or contain only ID #2.`

This i do not understand, why would it do this?

Comment: @PascalSenn I understand the GQL shown to imply "all companies, but only list their Office #2". This is the title of the question "how to filter a nested list": the question is how to filter the *nested list* (offices), not how filter out any of the companies themselves.

In fact the question detail states: "I would like ALL companies and their offices where the office id is equal to 2". In other words the correct answer would not filter out a company that does not *have* an Office #2. It would include the company, but yield: company.offices == []

Answer (score -2):

```
companies(
  where:{
    company: {
      offices: {
        some: {IsActive: {eq: true}}
      }
    }
  }
)
```

If filter is boolean then query doesn't work if Offices has IsActive bool field